# Can we add multiple aliases on one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, codeigniter, alias

My question is just simple,

Somehow I want to add **multiple aliases** for single column in my query, which will be used with in query, **Can i do it?**

e.g:

```
select username as id,fullname as "Full Name",(select login_date_time from login_log where login_id = ((select MAX(login_id) from login_log where username=users.username))) as "Last Login","secondAlias" from table users order by secondAlias
```

Note: I am using **codeigniter with postgre sql**

Comment: No, this syntax is invalid, but i'm curious for what?

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot add multiple aliases to a single column in your query. Query syntax of SQL allows for zero or one alias; there is no syntax for adding a second one.

Of course, nothing stops you from making a nested query, and selecting the same field twice with different aliases. However, this would introduce two identical columns under different names:

```
select
    username as id
,   fullName as "Full Name"
,   lastLogin as "Last Login"
,   lastLogin as "second alias"
from (
    select
        username
    ,   fullname
    ,  (select login_date_time from login_log where login_id = ((select MAX(login_id) from login_log where username=users.username))) as lastLogin
    from table users
) nested
order by secondAlias
```